# When I check if the session set, I am not able to log in to web site

Tags: php

This is what I use to check;

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    header("location: http://websitename.com");
}
```

After I type my email and password, I click log in and it goes back to index. But when I remove session check, the web site works just fine. So, I don't have problem in my login.php, here is some part of my login.php

---EDIT--- [SOLVED]

Found it. I had to call `session_start();` in my login file as well.

Comment: Take the condition around `session_start();` out - you need to call that on every page anyway

Comment: I've just tried that and it still doesn't work. I cannot understand why.

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` on the login page also?

Comment: Yes, I do. session_start();
if($_SESSION['email']){
    header("location: /home");
}

Comment: You should add `exit;` after each header. Plus, `if(!isset($_SESSION))` that could mean anything.

Comment: Okay found it. I had to call session_start(); in my login file as well. But why? to initialize session do I have to start a session?

Comment: Yes, `session_start();` must reside inside all files using sessions.

Comment: FYI: Don't edit a question's title by adding [SOLVED] to it. Either edit your question (which I did for you), or just delete the question. Edit: I closed it as a duplicate.